# Sitecore KickUser Programatically

Tags: pipelines, content-management

I have implemented some custom functionality to implement to kick the user, which is working fine but when I see `sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser.aspx` page then that kick user still exists. I also implemented `DomainAccessGuard.Kick()`

I know when the Sitecore login user exceeds then Sitecore redirects to `sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser.aspx` page and for all login sessions I can check in `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` but my question is in which database table Sitecore store this all login session and in which pipeline it do the entry into DB

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, I found that Sitecore does not save all login sessions into the database.

All `DomainAccessGuard` related functionality is available in `Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DomainAccessGuard` class in `Sitecore.Kernel` DLL.

To get all the sessions then need to call `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` and to kick the session programmatically it is required to call `DomainAccessGuard.Kick(sessionId)`

When a user logs in to multiple browsers or devices, multiple entries will be visible on the KickUser page.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out - `DomainAccessGuard` class is the one determining if a logged in user has access by keep tracking of active sessions. `Sessions` property is defined as follows:

```
private static List<DomainAccessGuard.Session> sessions;

public static List<DomainAccessGuard.Session> Sessions
{
  get
  {
    List<DomainAccessGuard.Session> newList = new List<DomainAccessGuard.Session>();
    lock (DomainAccessGuard.SyncLock)
    {
      if (DomainAccessGuard.sessions != null)
        DomainAccessGuard.sessions.ForEach((Action<DomainAccessGuard.Session>) (x => newList.Add(x)));
    }
    return Assert.ResultNotNull<List<DomainAccessGuard.Session>>(newList);
  }
}
```

List of sessions is stored in memory and is not persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the response, If I kick out the user using DomainAccessGuard.Kick() method then later if the kicked user, clicks on any page then it redirects to the login page which is correct but I can see DomainAccessGuard.Session also added session which I removed previously.

Comment: Session is added to DomainAccessGuard.Sessions after Login, so if you see the new session in sessions list after the login, it's correct behaviour.
DomainAccessGuard.Kick() removes the session from Sessions list.